# Can be use CountDownTimer within a loop?

Tags: android

I want to use CountDownTimer within a for loop but when I am using following code then CountDownTimer is running only once while I want to run it CountDownTimer as per given condition in for loop. it might be a silly question but I will be very thankful to you if I get some help. Thanks in Advance

```
       for (int i=1;i<=10;i++){
        Random random = new Random();
        totalques.setText(String.valueOf(i) + "/10");

        firstnum.setText(String.valueOf(random.nextInt(100)));
        secondnum.setText(String.valueOf(random.nextInt(50)));

         new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            time.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000) 
       +"s");
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
      }.start();

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Timer class for doing your job

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //one second elapsed
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000);
```

The schedule method say start directly and I want to be notified when every 1000 milliseconds elapse.
Don't forget to cancel the timer when you want to stop it with `timer.cancel()`

Inside the run you can decrement an int and when it reach 0 you can stop the timer